My home WiFi router enables restricted mode on YouTube and Google SafeSearch, despite having no parental control options
I have a new MediaCom router set up after a recent move, and entering the IP into the browser directs to a very simple page containing only static information.
How can I turn off Restricted Mode and SafeSearch, since they cannot be disabled normally?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The IP address of what exactly? Google, YouTube, your modem?

"entering the IP into the browser": The IP to control the router?

I entered the IP printed on the router.
